# Retornar lista de JSONs

Tags: json, python, flask

No path `/getAll` desejo retornar uma lista de JSONs porém obtenho um *'list' object is not callable*, por que isso ocorre e como posso retornar a minha lista de JSON? 
Anteriormente, *myList* se chamava *list* e após ler a seguinte definição de callable o erro persistiu.

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
>
> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
>
> These can occur when attempting to assign a value to variables with
>   these names, or by mutating their values.

Código

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import pymongo
from bson.json_util import dumps
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/getAll', methods=['GET'])
def getAll():
    try:
        conn = pymongo.MongoClient()
    except pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure, e:
        print "Could not connect to MongoDB: %s" % e
    db = conn['local']
    collection = db.teste
    myList = []
    for d in collection.find():
        myList.append(dumps(d))
    return myList


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

TrackTrace

```
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Mar/2016 16:51:44] "GET /getAll HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1478, in full_dispatch_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1577, in make_response
    rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 847, in force_type
    response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 57, in _run_wsgi_app
    return _run_wsgi_app(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 871, in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 2):

Daniela, vc precisa ver como está retornando esse myList, para retornar um json vc só precisaria usar o "return jsonify(myList)".

De acordo com os meus testes esse trecho de código só está retornando as keys do seu dict:

```
for d in {'a':1, 'b':2}:
    myList.append(dumps(d))
    # o retorna será ['a', 'b']
```

Vê como está retornando esse myLista, e se puder manda aqui.

Comment: Só pra acrescentar: o resultado dos seu método tem que ser uma string.

Comment: Mas ela quer retornar um json, não?

Comment: @victorhos Pelo o que me explicaram, as rotas só aceitam string como retorno. "Resolvi" retornando a lista de JSON em formato de string.

Comment: @DanielaMorais tendi, então tá resolvido né hehe, mas depois dá uma olhada nesse pedaço da documentação, talvez ajude:

> Creates a Response with the JSON representation of the given arguments > with an application/json mimetype. The arguments to this function are the > same as to the dict constructor.

<http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#module-flask.json>